# ES6 proxies can't be functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does that document means that future javascript proxy implementations would not have `Proxy.createFunction` and I will not be able to create a proxy which could be called as a function?

http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reflect-object

The Reflect object is a single ordinary object.

The value of the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the Reflect object is the standard built-in Object prototype object (19.1.3).

The Reflect object is not a function object. It does not have a [[Construct]] internal method; it is not possible to use the Reflect object as a constructor with the new operator. The Reflect object also does not have a [[Call]] internal method; it is not possible to invoke the Reflect object as a function.

Comment: You are confusing proxies with the `Reflect` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are citing parts of the spec about the `Reflect` object, which mean nothing for proxies.

The ES6 described in the page you linked does still have [Proxies](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-proxy-objects). [These objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) can be [`[[call]]`able](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-call-thisargument-argumentslist) (and even [`[[construct]]`able](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-construct-internal-method)). You're right that there is no `Proxy.createFunction`, all proxies seem to be uniformely created via [`new Proxy`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-new-proxy-target-handler). You would need to pass a callable object (i.e. a function) as the `ProxyHandler` for [creating](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-proxycreate) a callable proxy object.