# Do Proxies enable calling a non-function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Per my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069951/is-it-possible-for-an-object-to-also-be-a-function/36070369) question, chrome allows you to do the following (chrome 49):

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.fn = function(a) { this.a = a; };
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply: function(target, thisArg, args) {
        return target.fn.apply(target, args);
      }
    });
  }
}
var person = new Person();
person(3);
person.a; //3
typeof person; //object
```

Whereas FF makes you do this:

```
class Person extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.fn = function(a) { this.a = a; };
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply: function(target, thisArg, args) {
        return target.fn.apply(target, args);
      }
    });
  }
}
var person = new Person();
person(3);
person.a; //3
typeof person; //function
```

So requiring a call to `super` in a subclass constructor that references `this` is apparently correct according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), but in terms of allowing a proxy to make a non-function callable, which browser has the correct behavior here? Chrome which lets you, or FF which requires extending Function?

### UPDATE

Per Bergi's comment below, relevant spec section is [9.5.14](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-proxycreate), specifically step 7.

### FINAL UPDATE

This is a bug in certain versions of Chrome (I'm too lazy to test exactly which) Chrome 51 at least has the correct behavior of throwing an error.

Comment: @dandavis Because it enables a sort of operator overloading, you can specify how the function application operator `()` acts on a class, without necessarily having the instances of that class be functions. Not sure that doing so is all that great an idea, but it *is* an interesting one (at least to me). Indeed, javascript is definitely moving in that direction with the addition of well-known symbols. That returned proxy isn't limited to just the apply trap either.

Comment: @dandavis Oh yeah, there's no question that this is a 'bend the language in a potentially interesting way' question vs. a 'get important stuff done yesterday' question. Its anything but readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 proxies can't be functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26291836/1048572)? Also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29798915/1048572) for some spec references

Comment: "*in terms of allowing a proxy to make a non-function callable*" - that's clearly a violation of the spec

Comment: @Bergi so bug in chrome then? Sounds from your answer to the other question like objects without a `[[Call]]` slot shouldn't respond to `()` even if they've been proxied with an actual function call on the apply trap.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Btw, it you want to subclass functions I'd recommend `function F(callable) { return Object.setPrototypeOf(callable, new.target.prototype); } F.prototype = Function.prototype;` and then `class Person extends F { constructor() { super(function call(){…}} …}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't set “apply” trap to Proxy object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32360218/1529630)